# Python Dict w/Array Values Passed as Params?

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters, key-value

Alright so I have a dict with keys that point to an array of 5 values. These 5 values I pass to a class to sort out and feed me info etc.

### Main

So, this works, but my querstion is is there a better way of exytracting the array to pass to the 'weapon' class, or do i just need to `'wepstats[0],wepstats[1]'` etc? Or is there a better way of going about this? I'm all ears as Im only learning to do this stuff.

```
class Main():
    def weaponDamage(self):
        #print 15 * 2.22

        wdb = WeaponDB()
        wepstats = wdb.getWeaponStats('Sword')
        wep = Weapon(wepstats[0],wepstats[1],wepstats[2],wepstats[3],wepstats[4])
        wep2 = Weapon("Sword", 5, 55, 1.55, 2.1)

        print wep
        print wep2

        s = sayThings()

        greet = s.Say()

        self.crit = wep.getDamageCrtRND()
        self.scrit = wep.getDamageSCrtRND()
        self.avg = wep.getDamageAvg()
        self.high = wep.getDamageHigh()
        self.low = wep.getDamageLow()
        self.mod = wep.getDamageMod()
        self.norm = wep.getDamageNrmRND()
        self.name = wep.getWeaponName()

        print greet
        print "-----------"
        print "Name: " + self.name
        print "-----------"
        print "High: %s" % self.high
        print "Low : %s" % self.low
        print "Avg : %s" % self.avg
        print "Crit: %s" % self.crit
        print "--------------------"
```

### Dict

**EDIT:** Should I be making a DB of items in this manner in the first place? Is there a more logic method of doing this?

```
class WeaponDB():
    """Here be thine weapons of thy holy might"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.script = {
        'None': "Error: No Weapon stats to get selected.",
        'Sword': ("Sword", 5, 55, 1.55, 2.1),
        }

    def getWeaponStats(self, key = 'None'):
        try:
            return self.script[key]
        except KeyError:
            return self.script['None']
```

### Class useing the values as parameters

```
class Weapon():
    def __init__(self, name = "Stick", high = 1, low = 0, critMod = 1, scritMod = 2):
        self.rng = randNum()
        self.name = name
        self.high = high
        self.low = low
        self.critMod = critMod
        self.scritMod = scritMod

    def getWeaponName(self):
        return self.name

    def getDamageHigh(self):
        return self.high

    def getDamageLow(self):
        return self.low

    def getDamageMod(self):
        return self.critMod

    def getDamageSMod(self):
        return self.scritMod

etc...
```

Comment: in python you should not have `get...` functions, just reference `wep.name` instead of `wep.getWeaponName()`

Comment: Hmm ill keep that in mind, thanks. It makes sense. I was sort of doing that as an exercise. Im still actively getting used to things like objects and returning values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well you can do something like this:

```
class Weapon:
  def __init__( self, name = 'Stick', high = 1, low = 0 ):
    self.name = name
    self.high = high
    self.low = low

wepstats = ( 'Sword', 5, 55 )

sword = Weapon( *wepstats )
```

Then if you check your attributes you get:

```
>>> sword.name
'Sword'

>>> sword.high
5

>>> sword.low
55
```

Using `*wepstats` you pass the entire tuple as arguments for your constructor.